# Select all text between quotes, parentheses etc in Atom.io

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, atom-editor

Sublime Text has this same functionality via:

`ctrl+shift+m` or `cmd+shift+space`

How do I accomplish the same thing in Atom?

Answer (score 12):

Select all text between brackets is supported by default [Bracket Matcher](https://atom.io/packages/bracket-matcher) package.

Works for `{}`, `[]` and `()`:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

To select text inside quotes, you can install [expand-selection-to-quotes](https://atom.io/packages/expand-selection-to-quotes) package and use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>

Comment: To select text inside quotes, you can also use `Cmd+'` on a Mac

Answer (score 3):

Select all text between quotes, parentheses etc in Atom.io:
 Ctrl+Alt+,

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not natively support this functionality that I have found.
The closest thing I have seen is this package: https://atom.io/packages/select-scope